# Autowire the configuration class into another configuration class field

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

I have a configuration class RetryConfig , which uses configuration properties of class RetryConfiguration.

In class RetryConfig , I am creating one object SimpleRetryPolicy  field, which needs one property of class RetryConfiguration as below:

Ex:

```
public class RetryConfig {

//private static final int MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS = 5;

@Autowired
RetryConfiguration retryConfiguration;

private final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(retryConfiguration.getcount()); }
```

But with the above code, it fails.

whats i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field initialization (`SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy`...) happens before `@Autowired` is evaluated. Try one of those:

- make `SimpleRetryPolicy` also a bean (e.g., `@Component`) and autowire `RetryConfiguration` there
- create a constructor of `RetryConfig` with `RetryConfiguration` parameter and initialize `simpleRetryPolicy` in this constructor. The class then can look like this:

```java
public class RetryConfig {

//private static final int MAX_RETRY_ATTEMPTS = 5;

RetryConfiguration retryConfiguration;
private final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy;

@Autowired
public RetryConfig (RetryConfiguration c) {
simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(c.getcount());}

 }
```